# Change ENTIRE URL w/o page reload

Tags: javascript, html, url, browser

Is it possible to change the entire URI of a page without reloading the page and actually going to the new URI? I know we can change the URL relative to the root domain, i.e. stackoverflow.com -> stackoverflow.com/asdf

Can this be done?

stackoverflow.com -> quora.com

---

*I'm asking to make sure this is not possible.*

**EDIT: This question is different because I am asking if it's possible to change not just the path after the domain but the domain itself.**

Comment: I think that question addresses modifying URI without changing the domain name, i.e. stackoverflow.com -> stackoverflow.com/asdf

Comment: I hope [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page) helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it is NOT possible to change the domain, by design:

http://badassjs.com/post/840846392/location-hash-is-dead-long-live-html5-pushstate

Quoting the article:

> window.history.pushState(data, "Title", "/new-url");
>
> The last argument is the new URL.  For security reasons you can only
> change the path of the URL, not the domain itself.

Answer (score 1):

Answering you question of whether the following can be done:

```
stackoverflow.com -> quora.com
```

Using the HTML history API one is only allowed to push states to
within urls of the same domain, thus the answer is **no**.

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with this issue before and couldn't find a way of doing it without reload...
It's a part of the Location object http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp . It reloads the page even if you change the query params, that makes sense, being a different URL in the end.
The only thing you can do so far is to play with the # (hash) params.

One thing that might help you is the HTML5 History API http://html5demos.com/history . It modifies the url as you need in a way...but only for subdomains.